# "keyup", "input" in jquery not working on mobile device browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, input, onkeyup

I created a script, it is working on a computer's browser but not on, mobile's browser...

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Mobile Number"  id="Email" 
       oninput="this.className = ''" name="email" required>
<span id="email_status"></span>
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#Email').on('keyup input', function(){ 
        var email = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'availibility_email.php',
            data: {
                email:email,
            },
            success: function (response) {
                $( '#email_status' ).html(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I created a script, it is working on a computer's browser but not on, mobile's browser...

Comment: What exactly is it that works on a computer but not on mobile?

Comment: Javascript works on computer but not on mobile... @peeebeee

Comment: What about the script doesn't work? What's the behaviour you're expecting, what's happening instead? (Please see [ask])

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `keyup` and `touchend` events into the `.on()` *jQuery* method to trigger your code on both of these events *Desktop* and *Touch Devices*

```
$('#Email').on('keyup touchend', function(){
  //code
});
```